# Creating flutter Json Login form with user Basic authentication

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Have been stuck for quite a while on this step. can someone show me how to send a request such that upon pressing the "login" button a new instance of a user with Basic authentication is created. i would love to understand how to know how the headers are arranged to access the url database

```
     void Login() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      makePost();
    }
  }

    second part my json methond

     Future<Post> makePost() async {
    String Username = "denisPos";
    String Password = "moV4b90WqpHfghghsg";
    final response = await http.post('http://.60.4546.109:4520/postRequest',
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '$Password:$Username:$url'});
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    return Post.fromJson(responseJson);
  }


    class Post {
  final String phone;

  final String password;
  final String body;

  Post({this.phone, this.password, this.body});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      phone: json['phone'],
      password: json['password'],
      body: json['body'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Basic authentication you can have something like the following code:

```
Future<Post> makePost() async {
  String username = "denisPos";
  String password = "moV4b90WqpHfghghsg";
  var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");
  var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
  var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
  };
  var url = ...
  var requestBody = ....
  http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: requestBody, headers: headers);
  var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

  return Post.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

If you are sending a GET request you can omit the `requestBody` altogether.

```
http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
```

Comment: thanks chem it really worked. I only had to change "Accept": "application/json", to "setContentType":"application/json"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Future<http.Response> post() async {
    var url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    String username = "
    var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");


    var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
    };

    var requestBody = jsonEncode({ 'phone': phone, 'pass': pass});

    http.Response response = await http.post(
        url, body: requestBody, headers: headers);
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Utf8Codec().decode(response.bodyBytes));

    print("Body: " + responseJson);
  }
```